# when a sequence is not cauchy does it mean that it is divergent?

Tags: real-analysis

when a sequence is not Cauchy does it mean that it is divergent?

i have an example of a problem that shows that a sequence is not cauchy .i was wondering if i can usse it the same one to say that it means the sequence diverges too

Comment: A sequence of reals (or complex numbers) converges if and only if it is Cauchy.

Comment: so dat means my question is right then?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "divergent". If you mean "does not converge", then yes.

Comment: It is quite common to say that a sequence diverges precisely if it does not converge. If so, then yes, a sequence diverges if and only if it is not Cauchy. Some use "diverges" to mean diverges to $\infty$ or $-\infty$. In that case we do not have diverges iff not Cauchy.

Comment: @AxelFoley - Yes. Let $P$ be the statement "A sequence of reals (or complex numbers) converges" and $Q$ be the statement "A sequence of reals (or complex numbers) is Cauchy." Then a well-known result is $$P \Longleftrightarrow Q\text{,}$$
or $P$ if and only if $Q$. Using the contrapositive forms, we can find that $$\sim P \Longleftrightarrow \sim Q\text{,}$$ so therefore, a sequence of reals (or complex numbers) is not convergent if and only if it is not Cauchy.

Answer (score 4):

Every convergent sequence is a Cauchy sequence, and in **complete** metric spaces, every Cauchy sequence converges.  The real line $\mathbb R$ and the complex plane $\mathbb C$ are complete metric spaces.

Here's a proof of the first assertion (which is the one you seem to need).  Suppose $a_n\to a$ as $n\to\infty$.  Then for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that for every $n\ge N$ we have $|a_n-a|<\varepsilon/2$.  Consequently for every $n,m\ge N$ we have
$$
|a_n-a_m|=|(a_n-a)-(a_m-a)| \le |a_n-a|+|a_m-a| \le \frac \varepsilon 2+\frac \varepsilon 2 = \varepsilon.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It's divergent. We say that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n} = \alpha$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ we can pick $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n > N$, then $|a_{n} - \alpha| < \epsilon$, and it's Cauchy if for each such $\epsilon$ exists $M$ such that if $m, n > N$, then $|a_{m} - a_{n}| < \epsilon$. It's enough to show a convergent sequence is Cauchy. Pick $N'$ such that if $n > N$, then $|a_{n} - \alpha| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Then

\begin{align*}
|a_{m} - a_{n}| & = |(a_{m} - \alpha) - (a_{n} - \alpha)| \\
& \leq |a_{m} - \alpha| + |a_{n} - \alpha| & ( \textrm{triangle inequality})\\
& < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \\
& = \epsilon
\end{align*}

Thus a convergent sequence is Cauchy, and so a non-Cauchy sequence is not convergent.